# MonoDroid: Binding multiple libraries with multiple dependencies

Tags: xamarin.android

With the help of the "Binding a Java Library" document, http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Java_Integration_Overview/Binding_a_Java_Library_(.jar)#Overview, as well a couple blog posts, I have been able to make and use a binding against the ActionBarSherlock project. However, attempting a more complex binding has been a rather daunting process.

My current goal is to create a binding for a sliding menu project. This project is based on the Sliding Menu implementation crafted by jfeinstein10: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu. His project takes an (optional) dependency upon ActionBarSherlock, and both his project and ActionBarSherlock take a dependency upon the android-support-v4 library.

So far, I have only gotten as far as being able to create an Android Library Project with two modules, one for ActionBarSherlock and another for jfeinstein10's sliding menu. In this project, ActionBarSherlock takes a dependency upon android-support-v4, which is marked for export. The sliding menu module takes a dependency upon ActionBarSherlock. This project builds with no errors and can be used successfully in a vanilla Android app. It's worth mentioning that I'm fairly certain these two need to be joined into one library since some of the sliding menu code requires tweaking to leverage the ActionBarSherlock library.

From here, I am quite unsure as to how to proceed, and all my experimentation thus far has been wholly unsuccessful. What is the correct way to create a jar and/or jars to be used in a Java Bindings Library? How do I incorporate those jars into a Java Bindings Library such that a project using this library will have access to both the sliding menu and ActionBarSherlock functionality? How do I guarantee that the respective resources of sliding menu and ActionBarSherlock will be accessible within the final project?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still attempting to do this, but Xamarin has provided the bindings for SlidingMenu here: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SlidingMenu

I'm still trying to figure out how to properly reference ActionBarSherlock with it (it's bundled in as an embedded jar), but the sliding menu itself works quite well.

Comment: I just managed to get both ActionBarSherlock and SlidingMenu working with Intellisense. I compiled my Mono-SlidingMenu.dll with actionbarsherlock.jar's build action set to ReferenceJar. I copied both the SlidingMenu and ActionBarSherlock .dlls to my project and everything worked just fine.